# How to keep the latest X elements of a list

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I need to use a data structure that would keep the latest X elements of a list.  A colleague gave me this solution:

```
        int start = 0;
        const int latestElementsToKeep = 20;
        int[] numbers = new int[latestElementsToKeep];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            numbers[start] = i;
            if (start < numbers.Length - 1)
            {
                start++;
            }
            else
            {
                start = 0;
            }
        }
```

So after this is run, the numbers array has numbers 19-29 (the latest 20 numbers).

That's nice, but difficult to use this in the real world.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: 19-29 are the last 10 numbers, typo?

Comment: what actions do you want to do with that collections?

Comment: I need to process through the list quite frequently, so I want to limit myself to the latest X elements that occurred in real time.

Comment: @TravisJ: 19-29 are actually the last 11 numbers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a pretty standard [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).  My only suggestion would be to create a class for it or download one of the libraries available.  There seem to be a few promising looking ones near the top of the Google results.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[latestElementsToKeep];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    numbers[i % latestElementsToKeep] = i;
```

[Modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns the reminder of dividing `i` by `latestElementsToKeep`. When `i` reaches `latestElementsToKeep`, you will start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

For a range of numbers, you can use:

```
int keep = 20;
int lastItem = 29;
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(lastItem - keep, keep).ToArray();
```

To get the last items from any collection (where you can get the size), you can use:

```
int keep = 20;
someType[] items = someCollection.Skip(someCollection.Count() - keep).ToArray();
```